# Example of 4x4 symmetric matrix that is not diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, symmetric-matrices

Is the mentioned matrix possible? If so, what is an example of one?

Comment: Over what field? What kind of statements have you learned about symmetric matrices?

Comment: not sure what that means. any numbers - complex or real

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong over the regular field idk plz help, i'm stupid

Comment: @rigdonmr there's a difference between stupid and lazy, and in spite of your excuse I don't believe you're either.  What you need to do is check your notes or your textbook, and find the answer to the following: when they talk about a "symmetric matrix", what kinds of entries does the matrix have?  Are the entries necessarily real? Are they allowed to be complex? Is there some other field we should potentially be considering?

Comment: It is well known real symmetric matrix is diagonalizable by orthogonal transforms. You need to specify what field the coefficients of your matrix belongs to before this question make sense.

Comment: @rigdonmr in most contexts, "symmetric" means that the matrix has real entries, in which case we would tell you that no example exists.  In some contexts, "symmetric" really means *complex-symmetric*, that is, symmetric with complex entries; this is rare since the usual generalization of symmetric matrices is Hermitian matrices.  In this second case, the answer might be that there is an example.

Comment: okay i meant _complex-symmetric_. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: How did you figure out what the question meant?  I see that you're choosing the question with the more interesting answer, but it's a relatively unusual question to bring up. Also, I don't understand how you expect to pass without taking notes, looking at the textbook, or going to class; certainly, at least one of those things is necessary.

Comment: senior year, already have a job. Shooting for a C. @Omnomnomnom

Comment: @rigdonmr fair enough.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2007548/example-of-4x4-complex-symmetric-matrix-that-is-not-diagonalizable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It suffices to select a colum-vector $u$ such that $u^Tu = 0$, then take $A = uu^T$.  In particular, if $u = (1,i,0,0),$ we find
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&i&0&0\\i&-1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0}
$$

Comment: You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar, and I appreciate you.